# How to use RegEx to check if form input ends with .pdf

Tags: javascript, regex, html-input

So I have a text field on my web form, that users will use to enter a file path. I want to check if what is entered ends with .pdf

I have been looking around, and it looks like RegEx is what I need to use to get multiple browser support, but I couldn't find a good example.

HTML field

```
<input type="text" name="filelocation" id="filelocation" placeholder="Must include .pdf file extension">
```

Comment: @AvinashRaj will match '.pdf' anywhere in the test string.

Comment: @AvinashRaj More like `\.pdf$`

Comment: @DJDavid98 more like /.*\.pdf/

Comment: @JaredSmith "will match '.pdf' anywhere in the test string." ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the pattern attribute to do so:

```html
<form action="#">
  <input type="text" pattern=".+\.pdf$" placeholder="Must include .pdf file extension">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

It will also assure that there is some text before the `.pdf` at the end

Answer (score 3):

Regex is probably the wrong tool for this. Try

```
var arr = path.split('.');
if (arr[arr.length - 1] === 'pdf') {
  //do your thing
}
```

This should work fine in any browser.

If you prefer the regex solution (this isn't complicated enough for any performance comparison to matter, so its purely up to your taste) see CodeiSir's answer. It uses the HTML pattern attribute.

Comment: Why would you not use RegEx?

Comment: @CodeiSir all of the regexes presented thus far (including the one in your excellent answer using the `pattern` attribute) will match '.pdf' anywhere in the test string*. Granted, its not likely that '.pdf' would be somewhere else in the file path.
*ok, technically yours won't match it at the beginning, but you know what I mean.

Comment: `/.*\.pdf$/` will *only* accept ".pdf" at the end of the String. The `$` Symbol at the end of a RegEx makes sure the pattern is at the end of the tested String.

Comment: 'will match .pdf anywhere in the test string' could't really agree with that.
check my answer, i have even put sample input test case containing .pdf in the middle

Comment: @JaredSmith please note that in your answer (and don't steal my answer ;) )

Answer (score 0):

The expression you need is `/\.pdf$/`.

Example:

```js
document.querySelector('#filelocation').addEventListener('blur', check);

function check(e) {
 alert(/\.pdf$/.test(e.target.value));
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="filelocation" id="filelocation" placeholder="Must include .pdf file extension">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `match` method to check if the name string has `.pdf` at the end.

---

```js
var fileName1 = "something.pdf";
var fileName2 = "other.pdf.not.valid";
var fileName3 = "somethingpdf";

var outputDiv = 'output';

validatePdfFileName(fileName1, outputDiv);
validatePdfFileName(fileName2, outputDiv);
validatePdfFileName(fileName3, outputDiv);

function validatePdfFileName(fileName, outputDivId) {
  var outputDiv = document.getElementById(outputDivId);


  if (fileName.match(/\.pdf$/)) {
    outputDiv.innerHTML = outputDiv.innerHTML + "</br> valid pdf file name: " + fileName + " </br>";
  } else {
    outputDiv.innerHTML = outputDiv.innerHTML + "</br> invalid pdf file name: " + fileName + " </br";
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="output">Output</br></div>
```

Comment: try "somethingpdf" 

Answer (score 0):

I agree that RegEx is probably not the best solution for this. Due to that, I recommend Jared Smith's answer. However, if you really want to use RegEx for this, give the following pattern a try:

```
var PdfPattern = /*\.pdf$/i;
```

This pattern will match any string that ends in ".pdf" with case insensitivity (e.g., "something.pdf" is equivalent to "something.PDF", "something.PdF", etcetera).

If you are asking about this with the intent to allow file uploads, then, for security reasons, you should also do server-side checks to make sure the uploaded file is actually a PDF. Doing checks client-side in Javascript is not sufficient for security.

Answer (score 0):

The regex sentence that work for me is the following

```
^[a-zA-ZÃ?-Ãº0-9\s]{3,50}[.]{1}(([pP][dD][fF]))$
```

You can test it in the web site

https://regexr.com/

Comment: Not for me! It matches `aaaapdf`

Comment: @toto please check again